# VueJS 3 - Passing values to a grandparent component with v-model?

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

I have a question about passing values from a child component to a grandparent component. So I have this simple `TextInput` component:

`TextInput.vue`:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
});

defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

const input = ref(null);
</script>

<template>
    <input
        :value="modelValue"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
        ref="input"
    />
</template>
```

Now I use this component in the parent component `Company.vue`:

`Company.vue`:

```js
<script setup>
import TextInput from "@/Components/TextInput.vue";

defineProps({
  user: {
      type: Object
  },
  form: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
  },
})
</script>

<template>
    <div>
           <TextInput
                    id="company"
                    type="text"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full"
                    v-model="form.company"
                    required
                    autofocus
                    autocomplete="organization"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now `Company.vue` is used in `Setup.vue`. And `Setup.vue` makes use of InteriaJS and does this:

`Setup.vue`:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import Company from "@/Pages/Profile/Setup/Partials/Company.vue";

const props = defineProps({
    user: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    },
})

const form = useForm({
    company: null,
});
</script>

<template>
          <Company
                  :user="props.user"
                  v-model:form="form"
          >
</template>
```

So this is working so far, but I ask myself if this is the right way to do it. So I pass the `form` two times with `v-model`. One time I pass exactly the whole `form` and the second time I only pass `form.company` as `v-model` to the `TextInput`. Within `Company.vue` I can not use `:value` as the prop of the `TextInput` is `modelValue` - so it expects a `v-model`.

Comment: Don't change the prop, better use $emit('update:form',  newFormValue). You will have to emit the whole form value though, and not only the company field. I think currently you have warnings in the console about prop mutation

Comment: The issue is: I thought the same, but I do not have errors in the console. And on the TextInput I can not use :value and emit an event, as here I do need v-model, because the component expects "modelValue" as a prop.

Comment: You can use `:modelValue="form.company"`  and`@update:modelValue="onUpdateModelValue"`. And in that function, you make a copy of the form object, modify it with the new company value, and emit it with  `this.$emit('update:form', newFormValue)`.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know why I should make such an overhead, if the previous version with v-model just works fine. I dont get any errors regarding pro mutation. Maybe because it's an Inertia form created with useForm and therefore it's fully reactive?

Comment: I could also do something like this: listening to the update event in the textfield, and emit an "update" event to the parent component with the company name and set the value in the parent component. This should also work and I do not to juggle with the whole form object around. But thats exactly what v-model does :D

Answer (score 0):

use defineModel for two way binding in your custom component.

or if you want one way binding you should use defineEmits()
props is not a way to talk to parents.

Comment: There is no defineModel in VueJs :)

Comment: there is. check out this link: https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3

Comment: if you're using vue version < 3.3, then you can use vue macro library to use the same defineModel function.  checkout this link: https://dev.to/bitovi/new-in-vuejs-33-two-way-binding-with-definemodel-macro-270m

Comment: Thanks Mohsen! I was suprised, because the official docs habe no content for defineModel.